# How do I get my slideshow to repeat?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="images/natandadam.jpg"

var image2=new Image()
image2.src="images/gardaa.jpg"

var image3=new Image()
image3.src="images/marmaris.jpg"

var image4=new Image()
image4.src="images/gardab.jpg"

var image5=new Image()
image5.src="images/engagement.jpg"

var image6=new Image()
image6.src="images/gardac.jpg"

var image7=new Image()
image7.src="images/natandadamlake.jpg"

//-->
</script>

<script>
<!--
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1

function slideit(){
    //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
    if (!document.images) {
        return;
    }
    document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src");

    if (step<7) {
        step++;
    } else {
        step=1;
    }

    //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
    setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
}

slideit();
//-->
</script>
```

...and this calls it:

```
<img style="border:6px double #545565;"  src="gardaa.jpg" name="slide" width=600 height=400>
```

I want it to continue skipping through the images but it stops on the last one. It used to repeat when it only had three images; Now I've added more its stopped.

what do I change to make them repeat?

Comment: If you are able to do so, I strongly recommend using jQuery for this.  There are countless plug-ins for photo galleries, and they are generally quite easy to use.

Comment: Heh.. this code basically does everything wrong what one can do wrong: not using arrays where appropriate, using eval when completely unnecessary, passing a string to setTimeout (and thus using eval implicitely), mixing semicolonless and regular code.

Comment: OP ripped it directly from this tutorial: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/show2.shtml.  That site makes my skin crawl...

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your script quite a bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
var images ="natandadam.jpg,gardaa.jpg,marmaris.jpg,gardab.jpg,engagement.jpg,gardac.jpg,natandadamlake.jpg".split(",")
var step=1

function slideit(){
   document.images.slide.src="images/" + images[step]
   step++
   if(step>images.length) {
       step = 1
   }
   setTimeout(function(){slideit()},2500);
}

slideit();

</script>
```

A few tips:

1 - you don't need to use `<!--` and `//-->` to hide your script. The only browser that required this died in the 90s.

2 - don't use `eval()`, it's evil.

3 - since the images are now in an array, you can check add or remove and many as you wish without having to use `if (step<7)`. The code just inspects the length of the array.

4 - Use what is called an *anonymous function* in setTimeout instead of quoting code. Quoting code uses `eval(`) internally.